# Finding lucky numbers?

Tags: python, math

I have this rule:
A lucky number is a number with a 6 or an 8 in it, but not a 6 and an 8 in it.

The problem is to find how many lucky numbers in an inclusive range l, r.

First, I tried using a for loop. It worked, but it was slow.
Now, I am trying another method, but I'm not quite fond of it and it appears to be failing.
Here is my code:

```py
l, r = [int(i) for i in input().split()]

def nums_without_digit(l, r, x):
  """
  Returns the number of numbers in the range (l, r) that do not contain the digit x.

  Args:
    l: The lower bound of the range.
    r: The upper bound of the range.
    x: The digit to be excluded.

  Returns:
    The number of numbers in the range that do not contain the digit x.
  """

  count = 0
  for i in range(10):
    if i != x:
      count += (r // 10**i) - (l - 1) // 10**i
  return count
def nums_without_digits(l, r, x, y):
  """
  Returns the number of numbers in the range (l, r) that do not contain the digits x and y.

  Args:
    l: The lower bound of the range.
    r: The upper bound of the range.
    x: The first digit to be excluded.
    y: The second digit to be excluded.

  Returns:
    The number of numbers in the range that do not contain the digits x and y.
  """

  count = 0
  for i in range(10):
    if i != x and i != y:
      count += (r // 10**i) - (l - 1) // 10**i
  return count * 2
total = r - l + 1
total -= nums_without_digit(l, r, 6)
total -= nums_without_digit(l, r, 8)
total -= nums_without_digits(l, r, 6, 8)
print(total)
```

The idea is to start with all the possible numbers and remove those that are not possible.
The problem is, when give something like L=1, R=10, this program will spit out -34 instead of the expected 2.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are not testing the digits of these numbers at all.  I don't want to be unkind, but this code is completely in the wrong direction.  Can you easily compute how many lucky numbers there are between 1 and N?  If so, then compute 1 to Y and subtract 1 to X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem can be solved without having to inspect each individual number within the given range. We can analyse the problem as follows:

First look at how many numbers (unsigned integers) can be generated with at most  digits, and let's call that :

= 10

Now see what happens if we need to exclude any number that has a 6 in it, which means we have 9 choices per digit, instead of 10:

= 9

Continue the same logic to count the numbers that neither have 6 nor 8:

= 8

From this we can derive how many numbers have no 6, but have an 8:

=  −

Add to that the numbers that have no 8, but have a 6 (which is the same), and we have the number of lucky numbers that have at most  digits:

= 2

In a next step, we can look at a range from 0 to some number .

Here we could look at the first digit and see what happens with the numbers that have the same number of digits, but whose first digit is less, because there we can use the above formulas for the digits that *follow* that (reduced) first digit. For the numbers that keep the first digit as-is, we can use recursion.

There are quite a few cases to deal with. Here is some pseudo code that deals with each of them:

```py
count_lucky_less_than(n, d, forbidden=-1):    
    f = first digit of n
    m = n with its first digit removed
    if forbidden > -1:
        f is forbidden ?
            return f * B(d-1)
        f < forbidden ?
            return f * B(d-1) + count_lucky_less_than(m, d-1, forbidden)
        f > forbidden ?
            return (f-1) * B(d-1) + count_lucky_less_than(m, d-1, forbidden)
    else:
        f < 6 ?
            return f * L(d-1) + count_lucky_less_than(m, d-1, -1)
        f is 6 ?
            return f * L(d-1) + count_lucky_less_than(m, d-1, 8)
        f is 7 ?
            return (f-1) * L(d-1) + B(d-1) + count_lucky_less_than(m, d-1, -1)
        f is 8 ?
            return (f-1) * L(d-1) + B(d-1) + count_lucky_less_than(m, d-1, 6)
        f is 9 ?
            return (f-2) * L(d-1) + 2*B(d-1) + count_lucky_less_than(m, d-1, -1)
```

We can shorten that code a bit, as there are several expressions that are repeated in different locations.

Once we have that, we can finally solve the original problem of counting lucky numbers in a *range*:

```py
  count_lucky_in_range(lo, hi) => count_lucky_less_than(hi+1, num_digits(hi+1)) 
                                - count_lucky_less_than(lo,   num_digits(lo  ))
```

Here is all that in a Python solution:

```py
def count_up_to_n_digits_except_one(d):
    return 9**d

def count_up_to_n_digits_except_two(d):
    return 8**d

def count_up_to_n_digits_with_one(d):
    return (count_up_to_n_digits_except_one(d)
          - count_up_to_n_digits_except_two(d))

def count_up_to_n_digits_lucky(d):
    return 2 * count_up_to_n_digits_with_one(d)

def count_lucky_less_than(s, skip=0, forbidden=-1):
    d = len(s) - skip
    if d == 0:
        return 0  # base case recursion
    first = int(s[skip])
    if forbidden > -1:  # already collected a 6 or an 8
        rest_count = 0
        if first != forbidden:
            rest_count = count_lucky_less_than(s, skip + 1, forbidden)
        i = (first > forbidden)
        return rest_count + (first - i) * count_up_to_n_digits_except_one(d-1) 
    else:
        if first in (6, 8):
            forbidden = 14-first
        i = (first > 6) + (first > 8)
        return ((first - i) * count_up_to_n_digits_lucky(d-1)
                + i * count_up_to_n_digits_except_one(d-1)
                + count_lucky_less_than(s, skip + 1, forbidden)
               )

def count_lucky_in_range(lo, hi):
    return count_lucky_less_than(str(hi+1)) - count_lucky_less_than(str(lo))
        

# example run
lo =  452280
hi = 9518710
count = count_lucky_in_range(lo, hi)
print(count)  # 4869186
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this

```
N = 2000
S = {'6', '8'}
[n for n in range(N) if (s := set(str(n))) and (S & s) and not S.issubset(s)]
```

to find the numbers < N containing 6 or 8 but not both.

`:=` is the [walrus operator](https://realpython.com/python-walrus-operator/).

Comment: This is effective but slow in comparison to a more simplistic approach

Comment: As DarkKnight mentioned, this will be slow, and I am in need of an especially fast solution considering I will be running large ranges.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what complexity you are looking for, but you can try converting the number to a string first and then check if it has 6 or 8 for every i of N.

Simple solution:

```py
lucky = 0
for i in range(l, r+1):
  s = str(i)
  has_6 = '6' in s
  has_8 = '8' in s
  if not (has_6 and has_8) and (has_6 or has_8):
    lucky += 1 # lucky number
  # not lucky number
```

**What does this code do?**
Lets say L=600, R=800
It iterates every number from 600 to 800
lets say it is currently checking on number 602

1. It turns it into a string '602'
2. It checks if it has the character '6' in the string (yes it has '6')
3. It checks if it has the character '8' in the string (it doesnt have '8')
4. Checks if it has a 6 OR an 8 AND it doesnt have both

This check will fail for numbers like 608 or 680, thus not counting it as lucky number.

If you need a better time complexity, it's probably going to be done with math.

**What makes your code slow?**
Well, it's probably that you're using exponents for every loop and you're doing it 3 times, sometimes in Competitive Programming, if you're already using bad methods (i.e. exponents or O(n^3) or more), you have to try another angle of attack. Here, i turned the number into a string first and then it's easier to check if it has an 8 or a 6.
Sorry for the bad english, i hope you can understand.

Comment: O(n^2)? Where does that come from? What is n?

Comment: sorry, i didn't mean O(n^2), what i meant was iterating over a range of l to r and then iterating every char of str(N) (`in`).

Comment: The asker wrote: *"I tried using a for loop. It worked, but it was slow."* Why do you think your `for` is not slow?

Answer (score -1):

Keep it simple. This is fast and effective:

```
def count_lucky_numbers(lo, hi):
    count = 0
    for i in range(lo, hi+1):
        si = str(i)
        t = 1 if '6' in si else 0
        if '8' in si:
            t += 1
        if t == 1:
            count += 1
    return count

print(count_lucky_numbers(0, 10))
```

Comment: This is O(), so "fast" is relative to what your expectations are. This problem can be solved in O(log).

Comment: This is O(n log n), not O(n).

Comment: @trincot Please share your faster version. When I said that it's fast, that was in comparison to the answer from Diego Torres Milano (which is remarkably slow). The "speed" of the OP's code is irrelevant because it doesn't produce the correct results

Comment: Indeed, it is even O(log) as Paul says.